# Filter Entries from going into Apache Logs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, log-files

I have a setup where heartbeat is grabbing a website every couple seconds.  I would like to filter out these entries from the Access Logs.

Are there any apache directive or modules that will make so I can keep these entries from ever being written to the log in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, use [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) along with [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog)

e.g.

```
## Ignore anything from 127.0.0.1
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" nolog
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!nolog
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I might want '[Piped Logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#piped)'.

Although if anyone has a better solution, or any caveats to watch out for when using that, I would appreciate that. The major caveat mentioned on ths site I see is:

> "Piped log processes are spawned by
>   the parent Apache httpd process, and
>   inherit the userid of that process.
>   This means that piped log programs
>   usually run as root. It is therefore
>   very important to keep the programs
>   simple and secure."